# Cleaning column names in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Dataframe I receive from a crawler that I am importing into a database for long-term storage.

The problem I am running into is a large amount of the various dataframes have uppercase and whitespace.

I have a fix for it but I was wondering if it can be done any cleaner than this:

```
def clean_columns(dataframe):
for column in dataframe:
    dataframe.rename(columns = {column : column.lower().replace(" ", "_")},
                    inplace = 1)
return dataframe
```

print(dataframe.columns)

*Index(['Daily Foo', 'Weekly Bar'])*

```
dataframe = clean_columns(dataframe)
print(dataframe.columns)
```

*Index(['daily_foo', 'weekly_bar'])*

Comment: Show how the column names look like, you can add it to the question.

Comment: I highly recommend [pyjanitor](https://pyjanitor.readthedocs.io/) for this type of problem

Comment: try df.columns = [col.lower().replace(" ", "_") for col in df.columns]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can try via `columns` attribute:

```
df.columns=df.columns.str.lower().str.replace(' ','_')
```

**OR**

via `rename()` method:

```
df=df.rename(columns=lambda x:x.lower().replace(' ','_'))
```

Comment: Thank you, being spoiled by Python, I knew there was an inline solution but googling didn't get me there and I can never remember how lambdas work in a pinch. lol.